# Codepen sign up/log in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to get this sign up thing into Notepad. I'm hopeless and whatever I tried didn't work. I would appreciate if someone could take a look at the code and explain what each code file is going to look like (html,css ect).

Here is the link to the website: http://codepen.io/jack-doyle/pen/XXYXWp

Below you will find what I've copied so far.

Thank you for looking into it.

```js
(function() {
    var signup = $('.container--static .button--signup');
    var login = $('.container--static .button--login');
    var signupContent = $('.container--sliding .slider-content.signup');
    var loginContent = $('.container--sliding .slider-content.login');
    var slider = $('.container--sliding');

    signup.on('click', function() {
        loginContent.css('display', 'none');
        signupContent.css('display', 'initial');
        slider.animate({
            'left': '30%'
        }, 350, 'easeOutBack');
    });

    login.on('click', function() {
        signupContent.css('display', 'none');
        loginContent.css('display', 'initial');
        slider.animate({
            'left': '70%'
        }, 350, 'easeOutBack');
    });
})();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);


body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=650&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1375) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  overflow: auto;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:visited,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.container.container--static {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 40%;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.container.container--sliding {
  width: 35%;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 65%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 3px -2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.container.container--sliding .slider-content.signup {
  display: none;
}

.info-box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.info-box.left {
  float: left;
}

.info-box.right {
  float: right;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.heading.alt {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #E26A6A;
}

.info-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.info-text.alt {
  color: #aaa;
}

.button {
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 2% 5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.alt {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #E26A6A;
  border: 0;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

form {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
form input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hey.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Static container -->
<div class="container container--static">
    <!-- Signup prompt -->
    <div class="info-box left">
        <h2 class="heading">Don't have an account?</h2>
        <p class="info-text">Ethical celiac hashtag taxidermy squid. Wayfarers distillery narwhal, kombucha jean shorts selvage meggings.</p>
        <button class="button button--signup">Sign up</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Login prompt -->
    <div class="info-box right">
        <h2 class="heading">Have an account?</h2>
        <p class="info-text">Ethical celiac hashtag taxidermy squid. Wayfarers distillery narwhal, kombucha jean shorts selvage meggings.</p>
        <button class="button button--login">Login</button>
    </div>
</div> 

<!-- Sliding container -->
<div class="container container--sliding">
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="slider-content login">
        <h2 class="heading alt">Log In</h2>
        <form id="login">
            <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </form>
        <button class="button button--login alt">Log In</button>
        <p class="info-text alt"><a href="">Forgot password?</a></p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Signup -->
    <div class="slider-content signup">
        <h2 class="heading alt">Sign Up</h2>
        <form id="signup">
            <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
            <input class="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </form>
        <button class="button button--signup alt">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What's the error? Did you include the libraries that are included in the CodePen implicitly, like jQuery and jQuery-UI?

Comment: there is no redirection or form submit ,so you will see nothing happening

Comment: sign up user information and validation part to take user to next page is missing in the codepen.

Comment: I just add some links to the Signup and Login which works now ..but after signup , the user login will be authenticated and redirected to the respective homepage..which is missing in the code provided in the post
codepen url with dummy links-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZOpQYy

Comment: Fork it on CodePen, play with it as your own pen, paste the URL with specific issues you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place your html, js, and css code in the same directory. If you are going to move the file from codepen to Notepad you will need to import jQuery, jQuery UI and load your javascript file last.

In your html file place these scripts after your last div:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hey.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```